# Is it possible to define a timeout on dead keys on OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, keyboard

When you press a dead key such as an accentuation key, OSX will wait indefinitely until you press another key. I want that, instead, if you don't press the second key fast enough, it will just ignore the accentuation keypress.

Is that possible?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you talking about?

Comment: It is a personalized keylayout that I made using ukelele, @Tomg.